# Where would be the best place to put the captcha token in a REST API

Tags: rest, captcha, recaptcha, api-design

I'm designing a REST api that allow client side to POST (create) a resource. 
Let's call my resource is `Subscription` and my REST api accepts a Dto called `Subscription`
The POST request needs to be sent together with a captcha token that will be verified on server side.

My question is where would be the best place to put the captcha token, there're some options that I'm thinking about:

1. Directly inside `Subscription`
2. As a parameter in URL, e.g: /subscriptions?captcha_token=abcd1234
3. As a HTTP header
4. Create a new Dto that wraps `Subscription` and carry field `captchaToken`

Any other suggestion are welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: I didn't understand if you are going to use Post verb then how come you will use option#2? But leaving it apart your main concern which is best place to pass on the information about token from client to server then from my point RequestHeader is best place as neither you are going to store in backend nor use afterwards.By that way you are avoiding two things- 1. Not allocating space 2.If you use mapper then it be useless for it.

Comment: Hi @Aamol, the Http POST allow you to have parameters in URL, so option 2 is still feasible.

Answer (score 5):

For anything authentication or authorization related I typically rely on headers or querystring parameters.

Generally I don't like to commingle payload with auth-related material, nor do I like to encapsulate it.

Having it in an HTTP header or as a querystring parameter gives you a good amount of isolation there.  Also since it's independent of the request body you can implement broader auth controls for every API call without being dependent on the presence of a request body (important for GET requests which shouldn't carry a request body anyway).

Answer (score 2):

Using a HTTP Header is only an option if your clients can modify / send HTTP Header information. This approach does not work for Standard Browsers.

You are not filtering a resource, so a query parameter from the REST Point of view does not make sense, and you don't want to send the captcha answer as query parameter.

Usually the one submits the captcha information (id, answer) together with the form data (payload). You also usually display captchas  together with the form.

So at the end the only useful option is to send the captcha information as part of the payload / form data.

If you should put the data into your Subscription DTO or not depends on your design / preferences.

I'd suggest to use something like a `Subscription(Data)` and `SubscriptionRequest` where the `SubscriptionRequest` contains the `SubscriptionData`and the Captha Information (capcha id and answer)